# How to enlarge the boxed title frame of a tcolorbox environment?

Tags: tcolorbox

I created a `tcolorbox` environment to write summaries by adapting the code on page 15 of the manual. 
In this environment `\newtcolorbox{resume}`, the title is detached and placed in its own `tcolorbox`.

I would like to enlarge only the title frame with`boxrule=10pt,colframe=black` and I can't do it.
I tried to adapt the code of this question [tcolorbox, subtitle style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346561/tcolorbox-subtitle-style), but I did not succeed.

The code is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{ae,lmodern}                 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{soustitre/.style={subtitle style={colback=gray!15!white,
fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{black!25!gray}}}}}

\tcbset{titre/.style={title style={boxrule=10pt,colframe=black
}}}

\newtcolorbox{resume}[2][]{colframe=gray!50,colback=white,
beforeafter skip=0pt,
lower separated=false,
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}[soustitre,titre]{Title}
\tcbsubtitle{Subtitle\hfill }
\tcblower

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

How do I customize the `boxrule` width and its `colframe` color only for the title and not for the rest of the box?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `boxrule=10pt` ?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer No, actually, I want 2 or 3 pt but during the tests, I exaggerate to see more easily the effect of the change.

Comment: Well, see the output of the exaggerate version in my answer below ;-)

Comment: Happy TeXing and TColorBoxing ;-)

Comment: Even the color was exaggerated, I think I adopt `boxrule=2pt, colframe=black!15`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boxed title` which is added by one of the `attached boxed title...` options uses the style set with `boxed title style` and not `title style`, so change the `titre` style to from `title style=...` to `boxed title style=...`.

For more information see page 157 of the current (v. 4.11) `tcolorbox` manual.

The `boxrule=10pt` setting seems to be weird, however....

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{ae,lmodern}                 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{soustitre/.style={subtitle style={colback=gray!15!white,
      fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{black!25!gray}}}}}

\tcbset{titre/.style={boxed title style={boxrule=10pt,colframe=black}}}

\newtcolorbox{resume}[2][]{
  colframe=gray!50,colback=white,
  beforeafter skip=0pt,
  lower separated=false,
  leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
  title=#2,
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}[soustitre,titre]{Title}
\tcbsubtitle{Subtitle\hfill }
\tcblower

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]